# how to make background blur effects using only css3 and html5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to do i make blur background exactly like this image using only css3 html5 [See the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHDhX.jpg)

Comment: Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Good questions attract quick/good answers.  We are not a code-writing service for you.  Welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use filter property in css

```css
.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" class="blur" width="200px">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" class="" width="200px">
```

Comment: but how do i write content over it?